# Matplotlib heatmap axis labels not aligned correctly with cells

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

Here is the code I'm using for generating heatmap:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_values = [x for x in range(5)]
y_values = [y for y in range(7)]
z_values = np.random.rand(len(y_values), len(x_values))
plt.imshow(z_values, cmap='viridis', extent=[min(x_values), max(x_values), min(y_values), max(y_values)],
           origin='lower', aspect='auto')

plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

# Add labels for every y-axis point and every second x-axis point
plt.yticks(np.arange(len(y_values)), y_values)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(x_values), 2), x_values[::2])

plt.show()
```

This is example result:[image: Generated heatmap]

It is clear that the x-axis and y-axis labels are misaligned with the cel centers. How do I fix this?

Comment: what you mean by "labels are misarranged" ?

Comment: @HamzaNABIL i.e. there is 7 rows, so if you take a look: number 0 (yaxis label) is aligned correctly with row 0, number 1 is not aligned correctly with row 1, which results in number 6 being "below" row 6

Comment: Just change `extent=[min(x_values), max(x_values), min(y_values), max(y_values)]` to `extent=[min(x_values), max(x_values) + 1, min(y_values), max(y_values) + 1]`

Comment: @MattPitkin thats it, thanks. How do I close question from comment?

Comment: I'll add it as an answer and you can mark it as done.

Comment: As an aside to my answer (which uses `pcolormesh`), be aware that your code sets the origin to be in the lower left and assigns the `extent` accordingly, and then you invert the y-axis. You could have simply kept the default origin (upper left) and then assigned the `extent` consistent with that. In other words, you set the origin in the bottom left two different ways and then inverted that rather than directly putting the origin where you wanted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
extent=[min(x_values), max(x_values), min(y_values), max(y_values)]
```

to

```
extent=[min(x_values), max(x_values) + 1, min(y_values), max(y_values) + 1]
```

in the call to `imshow`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have an image, so you should be using [`pcolormesh`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html). `pcolormesh` has the option to pass the coordinates of the cells, so you don't need to adjust the extents.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_values = [x for x in range(5)]
y_values = [y for y in range(7)]
z_values = np.random.rand(len(y_values), len(x_values))
plt.pcolormesh(x_values, y_values, z_values, cmap="viridis")

plt.gca().invert_yaxis()

plt.yticks(np.arange(len(y_values)), y_values)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(x_values), 2), x_values[::2])

plt.show()
```

[image]